# JavaScript Canvas - stop animation after collision

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have problem with canvas animation. I created a character (black-evil box) that can be moved. After it touch another box (red) it stops. 
The animation is simple - the `player.x` deducted from `boxes[i].x` makes the blocks (and the camera) moving.
The problem is that "camera" (or viewport - don't know how to call it) should also stop.
I tried to change the variable `left` to `0` after a collision, but it's not working

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wA73R/

How to fix that? How to stop all things after collision?

Comment: I have checked the fiddle.. the black box does not even move... are u sure you have added all pertinent code ?

Comment: Try to use key arrows. I have no problem to move that box.

Comment: That's awesome you are totally using my tutorial aren't you :) Im checking out the code to see if I can figure it out. You're doing it a bit differently by adding scrolling.

Comment: @Loktar did you found the solution? I found how to stop box that is in 'collision' state, but rest of the boxes are still moving.

Comment: No :( I didnt actually get to spend time on it like I wanted. One thing I would suggest is start the player halfway in the center of the screen and *only* move the boxes, not the player *and* the boxes. I might be able to spend some time on it tomorrow unless someone beats me to the answer.